# Custom radio button is not selecting on click

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

```css
/* radio buttons */
 .radio-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}
 .radio-container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .radio-container input:checked .radio:after {
  display: block;
}
 .radio-container:hover .radio {
  background: gray;
}
/* custom radio button */
 .radio {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 .radio:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0.25em;
  height: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<form class="recharge">
  <div>
  <label class="radio-container" for="subscribe">
  <input type="radio" id="one-time" name="recharge">
  <span class="radio"></span>
  Subscribe & Save 10%
  </label>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label class="radio-container" for="one-time">
  <input type="radio" id="one-time" name="recharge">
  <span class="radio"></span>
  One Time Purchase
  </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have added custom styles to radio buttons on my website to give them a custom style. My HTML and CSS code is attached in the above snippet. However, now when I click on an input it does not select. I would ideally like to have this working without a JS component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the solution to your problem:

[Codepen link to the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/t9c53xoj/17/)

One of the issue I find was, you have not specified the color after the radio button is clicked and also the sibling selector was missing. I have added these lines specifically:

```
.radio-container input:checked ~ .radio {
background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

Hope it helps!! Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry I wasn't more clear. I was hoping that on clicking the circle, or pseudo radio button, that the radio button would be selected. If I was a user, that would be expected behavior for me.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for more details. Here is the updated jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/q0z9b1ho/2/

Comment: You can refer this w3schools link, which I used for my jsfiddle: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_radio